# Possible to modify an Android system image to boot directly to a shell?

Tags: android, c, linux, kernel

I want to take a rooted Android device (Google-branded) and have the kernel boot to a shell instead of calling the normal init binary that boots the Android system. In other words, I don't want any SurfaceFlinger or any Android stuff to run. I just want a shell displayed on the screen, with hopefully some way of doing input.

If this is possible, I will eventually write my own init program to do what I want using the existing device kernel with all its chipset vendor-supplied drivers, etc.

Any chance of doing this?

Comment: Probably. Have you tried? What happened when you tried?

Comment: I don't know about Android specifically, but the Linux kernel generally accepts the path to the initial program via ["command-line" parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) `init`.  So you would arrange to boot with parameter `init=/path/to/desired/shell`.  However that works on Android.  I also have no idea about any device for providing shell input.  That's probably the bigger issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, I've been doing this on desktop Linux for a while, but want to do it on Android. I'm comfortable implementing my own init, but I just need to know if all the drivers will load and I'll have access to all the devices in the phone.

Comment: @Synthetix, I'm not sure about modular drivers, but you don't need to do anything special to load built-in drivers.  I'm guessing that Android would rely on appropriate built-in drivers for the device on which it runs, but I don't know that for a fact.

Comment: your challenge will be more about finding how to install custom software on your phone in a way that won't break it

Comment: @user253751 True, but I can only start working toward that goal if I can bypass the Android stuff and work directly with the kernel. That's the first step.

Comment: no, you have to start with being able to install custom software. Then you can install software where the kernel boots directly to a shell. You will make that software by modifying the normal software for your phone.

Comment: @Synthetix Not sure if you've seen: https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/kernel

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I'm aware. I have read posts here where others have successfully repacked the boot image after making modifications to init.rc and booting the device using the custom boot image, so it seems possible to compile a custom init binary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://www.opersys.com/blog/android-10-on-beaglebone-black/ and https://github.com/android-rpi they have achieved "headless" android.